# numberformatexception error in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, numberformatexception

I am New at android stuff, really need help

I tried doing what others said in similar post, but i cant make it work, the error still pop out when i run it after clicking the button if the `EditText` (modal) field is empty.

I am using fragment in this code, since the other post using activity, i dunno what i miss or what part i am wrong at, please help me...

**here is my code**

```
public class Menu_PIAF extends Fragment{

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    } 

    ScrollView mScrollView = (ScrollView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.piaf_layout,
                container, false);

    Button button_submit = (Button) mScrollView.findViewById(R.id.button_submit);
    button_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //declare
            final EditText modal = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.value_modal);
            TextView result_piaf = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.result_piaf);
            TextView abc = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.notice);
            final String modalx = String.valueOf(modal.getText());
            //convert integer
            int modaly = new Integer(Integer.parseInt(modalx));

            if (modaly >= 5000) {
                String piaf = "Deposit";
                result_piaf.setText(piaf);
                notice.setText("Succeed");
            else{
                notice.setText("Error");
            } }

    });
    return mScrollView;
}}
```

**Logcat :**

```
 Process: com.example.fabio.tabdrawer, PID: 20089
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
        at com.example.fabio.tabdrawer.Menu_PIAF$1.onClick(Menu_PIAF.java:65)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Can you please share your logcat?

Comment: edited, logcat posted

Comment: Check out the answer. Please comment if you need additional help.

Comment: thank you very much, its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Menu_PIAF extends Fragment{
@Nullable
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    } 
    ScrollView mScrollView = (ScrollView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.piaf_layout, container, false);
    EditText modal = (EditText) mScrollView.findViewById(R.id.value_modal);
    TextView result_piaf = (TextView) mScrollView.findViewById(R.id.result_piaf);
    TextView abc = (TextView) mScrollView.findViewById(R.id.notice);
    Button button_submit = (Button) mScrollView.findViewById(R.id.button_submit);

    button_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //declare
            String modalx = modal.getText().toString();
            if(!modalx.equals("")) {
                int modaly = Integer.parseInt(modalx);
                if (modaly >= 5000) {
                    String piaf = "Deposit";
                    result_piaf.setText(piaf);
                    notice.setText("Succeed");
                } else {
                    notice.setText("Error");
                } 
            }
        }
    });
    return mScrollView;
}
```

Comment: minor fix when i tested it, the declaration variable need to be final